# Is there any way to get the permissions from a shared file - OneDrive?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, azure-ad-graph-api

How do I get the permission details of files **shared with me** on OneDrive using GraphAPI?

I tried the following code but the permission values are null.

```cs
IDriveSharedWithMeCollectionPage driveItems = await graphClient.Me.Drive.SharedWithMe().Request(requestOptions)
            .WithUserAccount(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.ToGraphUserAccount())
            .GetAsync();
```

Is there any way to get the permission details like read/write or readonly by using the GraphAPI from my shared Files?

The permissions are showing in the OneDrive at the  [Manage Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhCrd.png) option  but how do I get the details by using an API ? 
Is it possible to get those data by using such an API?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it but i am guessing that permissions are specific to the drive item which you can get it after fetching it only.You can get shared item like below:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var sharedWithMe = await graphClient.Me.Drive
    .SharedWithMe()
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

and then :

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var permissions = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items["{item-id}"].Permissions
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

The permissions relationship of DriveItem cannot be expanded as part of a call to get DriveItem or a collection of DriveItems. You must access the permissions property directly.

Effective sharing permissions of a DriveItem can come from two sources:

- Sharing permissions applied directly on the DriveItem itself.
- Sharing permissions inherited from the DriveItem's ancestors.

Additional reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-permissions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can I get the shared file details from my drive items  by using the second method? because when I tried the method it threw  404 error :( .

Comment: I tried the other options described in the documentation but all of them showing 404 error.

Comment: I haven’t got a chance to check , will check and let you know.

Comment: Have you checked the scenario for me?